# Nodejs Change server HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, https

I try change my server to HTTPS, but does not work fine. 
My page show like I created a new endpoint that returns anything.
In this case, I have 2 files, app.js with `express` instantiate and routes, and my server.js to execute the server getting the instance from express.

My app.js (server-side):

```
const express = require('express'); // app server
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parser for post requests
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
// instance of express
let app = express();

// endpoints here
// code .. code with routes, code...

module.exports = app;
```

My server.js (server-side):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const server = require('./app');
const port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000;


const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certificates/xxx.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificates/xxx.cer')
};

server.listen(port, options, function() {
  console.log('Server execute here %d', port);
});
```

Maybe is a newbie question, I can have one file with everything on it, but I would like to be more modular.

Someone can help me please, or explain what I did wrong with this case use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, what you are exporting from `app.js` is an express `app` object.  That's not the right kind of object to create an https server from.  Instead, you need to manually create an https server and then associate your express app with that.  You can see the Express doc for doing that here: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen.

If you look at the code for `app.listen()` in the [Express repository on Github](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L616), you will see that all it does is this:

```
app.listen = function listen() {
  var server = http.createServer(this);
  return server.listen.apply(server, arguments);
};
```

So, it is hard-wired to create an `http` server and has no way to create an `https` server.

To create an https server, you must create the server yourself and specify the `app` object as the request handler for it.

The general scheme for that is this:

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var app = express();
var options = {...};   // read certificates in here

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

Note that you manually use the `https` module to create the https server object and then you associate your Express object with that as the request handler.  The `app.listen()` interface in Express does not offer https server creation so you have to do it yourself.

---

If you really want to use your two files, then you could do this:

app.js

```
var express = require('express'); // app server
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // parser for post requests
//all endpoints is inside my app.js
var app = express();

// endpoints here
//code .. code with routes, code...

module.exports = app;
```

server.js

```
var fs = require('fs')
var app = require('./app');
var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 443;
var https = require('https');


var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('certificates/xxx.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('certificates/xxx.cer')
};

https.createServer(options, app).listen(port);
```

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, thanks advance for your help. I did your example and I get this error: ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE The page localhost does not work, no data has been send to localhost. You're know how are the problem?

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi - Your code doesn't show any Express route handlers such as `app.get('/', function(req, res) { code here})` to actually handle a specific request and send a response.

Comment: @SayuriMizuguchi - It appears that your original question is now answered as your http server is now up and running.  You now have another problem, probably related to `res.render()` and your templates which should be in a new question.   Perhaps you need to [register the appropriate view engine](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html), but we should not be discussing that issue here.  If you need further help with that, please post a new question.  You can verify your https server is working by just using `res.send("hello")`.